# Library for publish subscriber model with message queueing

Tags: c#, mqtt, data-distribution-service

I have a C# desktop plugin applications, I need dds implementation for plugin communication, I tried openslicedds, opendds and MQTT messaging protocol.

I couldn't find a light-weight solution  it, mainly because of lightweight C# server which need to install with my application is not available or most of them has dependency with cygwin.

Also we expect this must compile with mono to run in linux.

I tried with MSMQ too, but it's not enabled by default and it is not supporting publish subscribe pattern too.

Please suggest me a lightweight free solution if anything available.

Comment: What about implement the Observer Pattern from GOF? http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternObserver.aspx

Comment: From your explanation, I do not understand why a solution like OpenSplice does not work for you. Could you elaborate on what you mean by *lightweight C# server which need to install with my application is not available*?

Comment: @Thiago Observer pattern won't have persistence/queuing mechanism .

Comment: @Renier I need both server and client in the client PC, OpenSplice has an 60 MB Installation size and again it has dependency with Java. Also I think OpenSplice dds need run time license.

Comment: I found Mosquito project as a lightweight which implements MQTT , looking for it's C# client,  total installation including server is only 747 KB only in windows.

Comment: @Abdul Good you found a solution. As an FYI: OpenSplice does not have a dependency with Java. You can trim down its run-time installation to just include those components you need, which I expect would not be more than a few megabytes. OpenSplice Community Edition does not require any run-time license.

Comment: @Abdul This is off-topic, but please make sure to use the full and correct name of the user you are referring to in your comments, after the @-sign. Only then users will get notified about your comment. Your browser should help you by showing a small pop-up containing the names of the users you might be addressing -- just select the right one.

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek : Thanks for the advice, I will keep it in further posts, about OpenSplice could you please provide any link that I can trim down its runtime installation(server part).

Comment: @Abdul Sorry, I do not have a link. At runtime, you only need to keep a few daemon executables like spliced, networking/ddsi2 and durability, depending on your configuration. Additionally, the .NET assembly and some shared libraries are required. I would not be surprised if that would add up to a few megabytes only.

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek Thanks for the comment, currently I'm moving forward with mosquitto, any way later I need Opensplice dds too..., So if u find any helpful link or material in future just update here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found Mosquito project(http://mosquitto.org/) as a lightweight which implements MQTT(http://mqtt.org/), total installation including server is 747 KB only in windows.got C# client solution also for this. http://sourceforge.net/projects/mqttdotnet/

Answer (score 1):

RSMB ("really small message broker") is a free, tiny and trivially easy MQTT server.  We use it at IBM in lots of demos and small sensor and mobile projects (it is capped at 1024 concurrent connections).  You can download binaries for windows (160KB) and other OS here
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=d5bedadd-e46f-4c97-af89-22d65ffee070

RSMB also runs on Mac OSX, linux/x86, linux/arm, and other OSes.

For client, I'd suggest Eclipse Paho C client which builds just fine in Visual Studio / C#
http://eclipse.org/paho

Comment: RSMB:- its licence which states it is for evaluation only. and prperty of IBM. I found Mosquitto with opensource. Also eclipse paho poject  is in incubation.

Comment: Eclipse Paho is in incubation, but the code is actually the commercial C and Java clients that IBM has been selling for several years, now re-licensed as Open Source - so it is quite mature. We expect to join the Eclipse Release train next year if possible.